# Does json.dumps leak?

Tags: python, json, memory-leaks

```
import gc, json

class leak(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_LEAK)
while True:
    leak_ = leak()
    json.dumps(leak_.__dict__, indent=True)
    gc.collect()
    print(f"garbage count: {len(gc.garbage)}")
```

Using the following code under Python 3.6.3, the garbage count keeps increasing and task manager records steady memory increase.

However without indent `json.dumps(self.__dict__)`, no leak is observed.

**Update**: Code simplified to highlight the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no leak!
ref: https://bugs.python.org/issue32045

`indent=True` just makes json to use Python implementation instead of C implementation. Python implementation uses closures which reference one other. Simple example not involving json is:

```
import gc

def f():
    def g():
        return h
    def h():
        return g
    return

gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_LEAK)
while True:
    f()
    gc.collect()
    print(f"garbage count: {len(gc.garbage)}")
```

The "leak" is caused by using gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_LEAK). gc.DEBUG_LEAK includes gc.DEBUG_COLLECTABLE, gc.DEBUG_UNCOLLECTABLE and gc.DEBUG_SAVEALL.

gc.DEBUG_SAVEALL causes garbage-collected objects to be saved in gc.garbage for inspection. In normal circumstances they are collected.

**my reply:**

you are right. i realized later i actually had a leak in a com instantiated object, assumed it was a leak in the python and tried to find it using the gc module.

The gc documentation led me down the garden path.

> gc.garbage A list of objects which the collector found to be
> unreachable but could not be freed (uncollectable objects).

i assumed:

- cyclic references are unreachable but can be freed and hence collectable.
- `__del__` finalizer (with cyclic references?) objects are unreachable and cannot be freed and hence uncollectable.

Comment: so what is the answer!?

Comment: json.dumps(leak_.__dict__) uses c implementation. json.dumps(leak_.__dict__, indent=True) uses python implementation. python implementation results in cyclic references. if we now use gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_LEAK) these cyclic references are saved for inspection and it looks like a 'leak'.